# Conditionally assign type to variable in c++

Tags: c++, variables, types

apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't quite find exactly what I was looking for.

Essentially based on some condition I want to assign a variable A as either an int or a double.

Originally I thought I could do something like

```
auto a = (condition) ? 3 : 5.1;
```

However I realised the the int 3 is promoted to a double and so a becomes a double type regardless.

I understand c++ is strongly typed, but I would have thought there might be some neat trick to achieve this.

Thanks.

*** Edit / Clarification ***

I am not sure if the condition is known at compile time. I think not.

The way in which I would like to use the assigned variable is for example assuming I have a STL container `std::vector<std::variant<int,double>>`

Then I would like to assign a variable as either an int or double:
e.g.

```
bool check_state(std::variant<int, double> const& v) {
    try {
       std::get<double>(v);
    } catch (...) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

auto a = check_state(stack[stack.size() -1]) ? std::get<int>(stack[stack.size() -1]) : std::get<double>(stack[stack.size() -1]);
```

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Is `condition` known at compile time?

Comment: there is the datatype called [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which allows you to do this.

Comment: @AlbinPaul Not sure how to use `std::variant` in a conditional operator, but you could certainly use it in an `if ... else` block.

Comment: There are very few tricks in C++. Each object's type is determined at compile time. You cannot have objects whose types depend on runtime conditions. This is fundamental to C++.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Suppose `auto a = (condition) ? std::string("hello") : 3.14159265;` Now what do you want to *do* with `a`?

Comment: This question seems to need more details/clarity.  That line of code alone, if it did what was requested, would _do nothing_.  The optimizer would remove it.  As the very first comment mentions, we are asked how to do something without knowing _what_ they are trying to do.

Comment: Types are determined at compile time. If the condition is known at compile time this can be done, otherwise not.

Answer (score 3):

Using `auto` here is not possible as a general solution, as there are two possible types it could take. One way to - more or less - accomplish what you want, is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). You can think of it as a typesafe union:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    bool condition = true;

    auto a = [=]
    {
        std::variant<int, double> tmp;
        return condition ? tmp = 3 : tmp = 5.1;
    }();

    std::visit([] (auto &&x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }, a );
}
```

Given more context, for example if the condition is known at compile time, *generic programming* solutions are possible as well.

*Credits to [Drew Dormann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16287/drew-dormann) for suggesting `std::visit`.*

Comment: `std::variant` is indeed a way to manage types at runtime, but do you see what this code does if `condition = false`?  You get `std::terminate` because some of the type logic is still getting determined at compile time.

Comment: @DrewDormann True, for a false condition, it throws `bad_variant_access`. Manually checking the type is unavoidable. This is possibly the closest thing to what the original question asked for. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::visit`?  That function would make this code work as intended, regardless of what's in the variant.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm not, but I'll look into it now. I'll either update my answer or remove it.

Comment: make your last line `std::visit( [](auto&&x){std::cout<<x<<'\n';}, a );` and the code will work as intended regardless of the stored type.

Comment: @DrewDormann @Yun Hi guys thanks for the response, sorry if I haven't been clear enough. I guess I would probably like to do something like; `auto c = std::visit([] (auto &&x) { return x; }, a );`  which I don't think is possible ? See - coliru.stacked-crooked.com/… –

Comment: @cheese this question got closed because a good answer requires you to explain what your real goal is.  Putting a value in a variable is never the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a variant, here's another solution using an immediately invoked lambda, this returns the expected value:

```
constexpr bool condition = true;
auto a = [=]() {
    if constexpr (condition) return 3;
    else return 5.1;
}();

std::cout << "type of a: " << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
std::cout << "value of a: " << a << '\n';
```

Notice the lambda is implicitly constexpr, the condition must be captured and not passed as a parameter to ensure compile-time evaluation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response is this possible to do without have a constexpr condition. I don't think my condition is known at compile time. Please see - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/?fbclid=IwAR0_3BsTs3I4bm1BGUe2vn7V7I1wqCVry7p13fX2irfEn_PYHatfwmsgHPIa/daeee37c147f7830a/8b8cb02555692ffa